# How can I extract NON-HLOS.bin from my Motorola Moto G xt1032?

Tags: file-system

I want to extract that file in order to restore my wi-fi on another Motorola Moto G

How can I do that ?

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). *Explain* to us your *original problem*.

Comment: I'm sure that it is the missing file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a root shell/terminal:

```
dd if=/dev/block/platform/*/by-name/modem of=/sdcard/NON-HLOS.bin
```

On some devices it might be `radio` instead of `modem` and you can, of course, place it somewhere other than `/sdcard`.

Note also that it will typically be padded with zeroes on the end — for example, the NON-HLOS.bin I flashed was 57.1 MB but when I retrieve it with the above method the resulting file is 64 MB (with it being identical apart from the padding).

Comment: Thanks, is it normal that from a file explorer like solid explorer, the file size is 0b ?

Comment: @Clippy No, I wouldn't think so, but I haven't used that app.